# How to fix "expected primary-expression before '%' token" error code?

Tags: communication, python

I'm trying to use this code to get temperature and humidity values from DHT11 sensor and send it to Python and I need to write the temperature and humidity values in the same line. But I keep getting the error code

> expected primary-expression before '%' token

How can I fix this?

```
#include <dht.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
char buffer [64];

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 7

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  a = DHT.temperature;
  b = DHT.humidity;
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  sprintf(buffer, %d %d, a, b);
  Serial.print(buffer);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: The error mentioned a line number.  Did you look at that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes on the second parameter of `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d %d", a, b);
```

Comment: please don't answer syntax error questions. they are off-topic